# Is there a way to make EF 5 code first migrations use a sql server database in ASP.NET MVC 4 for everything?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-migrations

I would like for it to use SQL Server by default for everything when I start a new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application project. By default when you run this project it creates a LocalDb instance and creates the following tables in it:

- webpages_Membership
- webpages_OAuthMembership
- webpages_Roles
- webpages_UsersInRoles
- UserProfile

I have been able to use a code first migration to put the UserProfile table into a SQL server database. However, I have not been able to accomplish this with the other 4 tables.

Obviously my goal is to start with a single SQL Server database and have all of the tables for the application contained within the single database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs file, this is where the WebSecurity database initialization is. You need to modify it with the correct connectionStringName. Example:

Change

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

to

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyRealDBConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

IF you want to copy the structure of the web security tables to use with Code First, there is an article .... which I cannot find at the moment ... give me a few.

Well I could not find it - but honestly - it was a pain. The easiest way, since you have the DB generated already, might be to use an Code First reverse engineer tool like [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d). This will do most of the work for you. Then just add the classes to your DbContext, create a migration, and update your real database.

Also - you may need to make more modifications than this - depending on your Context name and such.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to only create those tables in your existing db, you should perform 2 steps.

First, change the connection string of db initialization as what @Jack said.

Second, in your DbContext, change the constructor like this:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    publicMytDbContext()
        : base("MyRealDBConnection")
    {

    }

    // ...
}
```