# Entity Framework "Code First" not creating database tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I've created my objects in ASP.NET MVC4, and after running the application, only UserProfile table is auto created, not the other one corresponding my class.

Followed this advice: [Entity Framework 4.1 Code First not creating tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250297/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-not-creating-tables) and got this error:

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

**Question 1:** What is the correct way to do this in Code First approach?

**Question 2:** Why is the built-in UserProfile created, and not the table for my object? What makes the difference?

Comment: Can you provide your other class? Are you having proper data annotations?

Comment: can you post your context?

Answer (score 1):

Please read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460372/is-there-a-way-to-make-ef-5-code-first-migrations-use-a-sql-server-database-in-a/17462295#17462295) ... same situation I think. UserProfile table created, others not created. My guess is that you've switched to an actual MSSQL DB and not a local DB, but have not pointed your WebSecurity DB initialization to the new database.