# SimpleMembership initializer does not create all the tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Folks,

After creating a new ASP .NET MVC 4 application, here is what I did:

1. From the database explorer, deleted all the tables in the default connection.
2. Edited AccountModels.cs to and added a few more tables.
3. Updated UsersContext class to reference the new tables:
     public class UsersContext : DbCOntext {

   ```
     ...
     DbSet<Items> Items {get; set; }
   ```

   }
4. Ran the application.

In the debugger, I see that the following line is invoked:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

However, when I look at the database, only the five tables relevant to SimpleMembershipProvider are getting created. My additional tables are not getting created.

I am wondering if there is some step that I missed.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: Why do you "deleted all the tables in the default connection"?  I think the four webpages_* tables should not be modified.  The UserProfile table can be changed as long as you have the two columns (default UserId, UserName) specified in the parameters in the InitializeDatabaseConnection method you have shown.  I have done this successfully before.

Comment: What @DarthVader says is true - its a pain to integrate the two. I have a post ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460372/is-there-a-way-to-make-ef-5-code-first-migrations-use-a-sql-server-database-in-a/17462295#17462295 .. where I describe an easy way to model the default membership tables and add them to your DbContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. I eventually figured it out. The default InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute class is geared to create only the required tables (and columns) for simple membership. You create your own initializer class that inherits  from CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<>. Now, you can just delete and recreate an empty database. When you run your application, ALL your tables will automatically get created.

Peter

Answer (score 2):

You need to create another DbContext class for your domain model.

Using the same DbContext, UsersContext will cause you many problems in the future. I had so many problems with that. and turned out, you need a seperate DbContext for your domain model.